# Bootstrap 3 mobile dropdown menu link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have strange problem from the mobile menu. When I want to create a version for small, medium, large device 4 columns dropdown menu.

In the menu on the Extra Small Devices <768px:

When I click Link1>TEST
He is brings me to the url located under LINK2. Why?

If a click Link3>TEST
(Aslo 4 columns menu for larger device)
Everything is OK.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Test menu</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->


<style>
body{
    background: #000000;

}


.nav>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li{
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover,.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:focus, .nav .open>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  background: none;

}
.navbar a, .dropdown-menu>li>a, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .navbar-toggle{
 color: #ffffff;

}
.dropdown-menu{
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow:none;

}



.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
    color: #fff;
    background: #fff;
}



@media(min-width:768px) {
     #double li  { width:25%;
    float:left;
  display:inline;
  margin-bottom: 14px;


}
.navbar, .dropdown-menu{
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
border: none;
min-width: 500px;

}
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
     #double li  { width:100%;
    float:left;
  display:inline;



}
.navbar, .dropdown-menu{
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
border: none;
min-width: auto;

}

}


</style>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="">Home</a></li>
                        <li class=" dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="double">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.example1.com">TEST</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.example2.com">TEST</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.example3.com">TEST</a>
                                </li>
                                 <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.example4.com">TEST</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.example5.com">Link2</a></li>

                        <li class=" dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="double">
                                <li><a href="http://www.example6.com">Test1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.example7.com">Test2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.example8.com">Test3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.example9.com">Test4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

**Ok I solved this problem.** 
The answer if someone had the same problem

```
@media(min-width:768px) {  
 #double { 
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
       -moz-column-count: 4;
            column-count: 4; 
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
     #double {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
       -moz-column-count: 1;
            column-count: 1;
}
```

Comment: According to your example, all the links under Link 1 go to the same location. Your [mcve] doesn't have to include the same links as in your real code, but your code should still duplicate the problem in your post.

Comment: @BSMP Ok I edit and past rest HTML code

Comment: You cannot have 2 id's that are the same on one page. You use the id `double` twice. Id stands for identifier, and should only be used once on a page for specific targetting. Consider making that a class.

Answer (score 1):

You've given both dropdowns the same ID. Not sure why that caused the behavior you're getting but fixing those fixes the menus:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" class="">Home</a></li>
    <li class=" dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="double1">
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.example1.com">TEST</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.example2.com">TEST</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.example3.com">TEST</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.example4.com">TEST</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example5.com">Link2</a></li>

    <li class=" dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="double2">
        <li><a href="http://www.example6.com">Test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example7.com">Test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example8.com">Test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example9.com">Test4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Normally, I'd do a runnable snippet but your styles were being overwritten by the Bootstrap styles here.